# parse linux paths as columns in a .csv file bash

Tags: awk, csv, text-formatting

I have a .csv data file which I have manipulated to look like this:

```
   -------------PATH AND FILE NAME--------,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS
   /Proj/abc/app/app_pit/conf/HUB_TEST.apx,uJones,4/24/2018,5:55:58,OK
   /Proj/abc/app/app_pit/conf/test_acqit1.apx,uSmith,3/8/2018,10:16:41,OK
   /Proj/abc/app/app_pit/conf/test_bkfs.apx,uHarry,/26/2018,9:47:03,OK
```

Which was fantastic!  Until, I got some feedback and a request to subdivide the "PATH AND FILE NAME" column as such:

```
    LB,-PROJ---,FILENAME----,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS
    app,app_pit,HUB_TEST.apx,uJones,4/24/2018,5:55:58,OK
    app,app_pit,test_acqit1.apx,uSmith,3/8/2018,10:16:41,OK
    app,app_pit,test_bkfs.apx,uHarry,/26/2018,9:47:03,OK
```

Omitting "/Proj/abc" from all records and removing "conf" from the path

I tried many different awk, sed, tr, etc apps but cant seem to get this right.  Perhaps there is some looping logic to employ here?

Comment: Are `/Proj/abc/` and `/conf/` literal constant strings here? or do they vary from record to record?

Comment: where does `LB,-PROJ---` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the header, and assuming that the text in the file has no spaces at the start of the line (it has in your question):

```
$ sed -e 's@/Proj/abc/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/conf/@\1,\2,@' file
-------------PATH AND FILE NAME--------,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS
app,app_pit,HUB_TEST.apx,uJones,4/24/2018,5:55:58,OK
app,app_pit,test_acqit1.apx,uSmith,3/8/2018,10:16:41,OK
app,app_pit,test_bkfs.apx,uHarry,/26/2018,9:47:03,OK
```

The `sed` command captures the `app` and `app_pit` strings (which I assume can vary), and replaces the path in the original data with these with commas in-between while leaving the last bit of the path as its own field.

Redirect this to a new file and then fix the header (if needed).

Comment: @steeldriver Ah, the `conf` has to go too. I will avoid hardcoding `app` there though. Thanks!

Comment: Yes good idea - it's not clear how variable the OP's records are

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's|-------------PATH AND FILE NAME--------,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS|LB,-PROJ---,FILENAME----,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS|' -e 's|/Proj/abc/||g' -e 's|/conf||g' -e 's|/|,|2' -e 's|/|,|1' file
```

Just an extended set of stream replacements.

The first changes the first line to starting with the string beginning with `LB` that you want.

The second removes /Proj/abc/.

The third removes /conf.

The fourth and fifth replace the 2nd and 1st forward slashes with commas.

Output:

```
LB,-PROJ---,FILENAME----,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS
app,app_pit,HUB_TEST.apx,uJones,4/24/2018,5:55:58,OK
app,app_pit,test_acqit1.apx,uSmith,3/8/2018,10:16:41,OK
app,app_pit,test_bkfs.apx,uHarry,/26/2018,9:47:03,OK
```

Comment: Hello Nasir and thanks for your reply.  I notice your solution has still has "PATH and FILENAME" which needs to be divided into LB, PROJ, FILENAME but neither way is printing the header.  The data looks great!  Any ideas?

Comment: @SSDdude The `sed -e` only sends the changes to std output and it changes "PATH and FILENAME" to LB, PROJ, FILENAME when I do it on my machine with the output as what's above in my answer. If you want the changes to the file, add `-i` after `sed`. Are you using `gnu sed`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this will catch fire if any of the filenames have a `,` or `/` in them:

```
$ awk -F "[/,]" -v OFS="," 'BEGIN { print "LB", "-PROJ--", "FILENAME----", "USER--", "DATA-----", "TIME---", "STATUS" }NR!=1{print $4,$5,$7,$8,$9"/"$10"/"$11,$12,$13}' input
LB,-PROJ--,FILENAME----,USER--,DATA-----,TIME---,STATUS
app,app_pit,HUB_TEST.apx,uJones,4/24/2018,5:55:58,OK
app,app_pit,test_acqit1.apx,uSmith,3/8/2018,10:16:41,OK
app,app_pit,test_bkfs.apx,uHarry,/26/2018,9:47:03,OK
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "," }
     NR == 1{ $1 = "LB,-PROJ---,FILENAME----" }
     NR > 1{
         gsub("/(Proj/abc/|conf)", "", $1);
         gsub("/", ",", $1)
    }1' file
```

The output:

```
   LB,-PROJ---,FILENAME----,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS
   app,app_pit,HUB_TEST.apx,uJones,4/24/2018,5:55:58,OK
   app,app_pit,test_acqit1.apx,uSmith,3/8/2018,10:16:41,OK
   app,app_pit,test_bkfs.apx,uHarry,/26/2018,9:47:03,OK
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

```
    sed -e 's|-------------PATH AND FILE NAME--------,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS|LB,-PROJ---,FILENAME----,USER--,DATE-----,TIME---,STATUS|' -e 's|/Proj/abc/||g' -e 's|/conf||g' -e 's|/|,|2' -e 's|/|,|1' file
```

Thanks Nasir Riley, your sed solution worked flawlessly!!

Comment: The right thing to do here is to [accept Nasir's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) (click the checkbox), not repeat their answer.